# Add a column in output of a command through Shell Script

Tags: shell

```
[root@vms01 ~]# xm list

Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)

0004fb00000600000484f2c141c45ebd             2 32768     8     r----- 17545619.9
0004fb000006000010777a59f9d0789a           568 33083     4     -b----  92648.9
0004fb00000600001ebd7c8a657da3a7           504  4096     2     r----- 164842.4
```

Now i need to append a column say "Simple Name" at the last. How can i achieve it through shell script?

Comment: And what shall be this `Simple Name`?  Exactly this string for each line?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
xm list | while IFS='' read x; do printf "%-83s %s\n" "$x" "Simple Name"; done
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)     Simple Name
Domain-0                                     0  1793     2     r----- 1815788.7     Simple Name
18732649712347                            4563 16384     1     r-----   3553.7      Simple Name
86734762346293                            4567 16384     1     r-----   2967.5      Simple Name
98634963425246                            4569  8192     8     r-----  11244.8      Simple Name
32472034857723045974                      2348  4000     8     r----- 11252960.7    Simple Name
2234827345084                              535 128000    32     r----- 55286918.7   Simple Name
947305273405782034523457                       16000     1                30.6      Simple Name
```

Comment: Thats very good suggestion. But what if "Simple Name" is variable. for ex. line 1 its test VM1, line 2 its Dev VM2.  How can i put variable value in each line.

Comment: You've got the line in the variable `$x`.  Instead of `"Simple Name"` you could print whatever you like, e. g. `"${x:0:4}"` to get the first 4 characters of the line.  Or `"$(echo "$x" | grep -o ' r.....')"` to get the state column.  That's completely up to you.  This answer just answers how to add the column (because that's what you asked), not how to derive some values for this column (because you didn't ask for this).